# Setting up the correct model association Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

Im trying to figure out the best path here, a previous question hasn't shed much light on the matter, but thats probably due to my explanation, so im going to try and break it down into smaller chunks to hopefully gather some more understanding around the problem whilst learning in bitesized chunks

**Scope of application**

A football prediction app where a user makes a predition of the score in upcoming games. Depending on whether they have predicted correctly they will be assigned some points.Each user can create a team which will then be part of a league.

**Current Models**

```
class User
  has_many predictions #prediction model has user_id as FK
  has_many :teams #team model has user_id as FK
  attr_accessible :prediction_id
end    

class Team   
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :team_name, :user_id, :key
end

class Prediction
  has_many fixtures #to allow predictions from multiple users<br> 
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :home_score, :away_score, :fixture_date, :fixture_id, :user_id
end

class Result
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :fixture_date, :home_score, :away_score
end
```

My question is should i have a separate model such as point to store the points gained from a users prediction? So for example if a user predicts the score correctly they would be given 3 points.

In the `Point` model i would have the attributes

```
result_id, prediction_id, allocated_points
```

so in here I could compare the prediction against the result and allocate points..

Any advice appreciated as really stumped on this one

Answer (score 0):

I dont't think this has a right/wrong answer. Its hard to say without seeing the assosiations and attributes of each model but I would start by calculating their points:

```
class Predication
  def correct?
    fixture.result == result
  end
end

class User
  def points
    predications.select(&:correct?).size * 3
  end
end

class Team      
  def points
    users.map(&:points).inject(&:+)
  end
end
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, i have updated my associations and attributes in the question if you wouldnt mind taking a second look

Comment: I'm unsure what Fixtures is for, you seem to indicate a Predication can have many Users? Should a Predication not belong to just one User?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Point should not be a model. It should be a column in user table.
You should calculate point from prediction and result and update the point of the associated user.

But its just my point of view, I may be completely wrong.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have updated my question slightly, a user can create a team , so would it be wise to assign the points to the team rather than the user? or what about the prediction model as then I would get the points earned for each prediction rather than a total?